# In Android SDK - How can I locate the word at a pixel location pressed by the user in an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am building an application where the user enters text into an EditText.

I would like to be able to have the user touch a word, and detect the word at the pixel location they touched. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Spans. Particularly, [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html). You can assign a span to a part of the text to give that part of the text some "features" (in this case, it will make the text clickable).

There's a [nice example](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/customizing-the-android-edittext-behavior-with-spans/), in which custom Spans extending ClickableSpan are used in EditText to make the text display more user-friendly.

Comment: Hmm, the clicks are not getting captured - any ideas?

Comment: This will be a quite generic suggestion - but when I'm trying to implement something that I don't fully understand yet, I'm starting with a working example and then I'm modifying it, to fit my needs. With this approach, I can easily spot the place when I made a bug (the whole thing just stops working). So, You can take the PhotoRocket example, put in a new test app and modify it to fit your needs. That's the case if the example works.

Comment: It's a great suggestion and a great example. However it is not complete source so it can't be executed. Will poke around some more - thanks - this is the approach I expect to use (if I can ever get the click working!)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code...

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent mEvent) {

```
     Layout layout = ((TextView) view).getLayout();
        int x = (int)mEvent.getX();
        int y = (int)nEvent.getY();
        if (layout!=null){
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int charAtTouch = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
            Log.i("position", "" + charAtTouch);
            }
        return true;


}
```

Comment: This suggestion has potential, but how do you figure out the actual character or word that was touched?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can get position of cursor appeared in textbox after touch and locate the word?